# jquery delegate onload event-handler for newly created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am delegating event handler to elements that are not yet created like this:

```
$('body').on('change', '#some_elementid', function() {
  //actions
});
```

this is working,

But I want `actions` to run right after the element is created without any other events. `load` doesnot seem to work..

what is possible here to achieve `onload` ?

**UPDATE**:

```
<div id="some_elementid">
    <button id="addmore">+ add more</button>
</div>
```

by clicking on `+ add more`, another container will be inserted into `#some_elementid` which will have some fields. I want to prepopulate those fields during inserting.

without prepopulation, it will look like:

```
<div id="some_elementid">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="id_0">
      <input type="text" id="id_1">
      ...
    </div>
    <button id="addmore">+ add more</button>
</div>
```

I want to manipulate during onload and show like:

```
 <div id="some_elementid">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="id_0">
    </div>
    <button id="addmore">+ add more</button>
</div>
```

**JSfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/yugaj2x2/

I want to hide `"two"` while inserting. because later on clicking some other radio button, `"two"` will show up, but not now. this is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: You should provide relevant jQuery/javascript code used to populate the container, a ***jsFiddle*** would be great. There is not enough info to see why would you need to 'delegate' onload event. Are you using some iframe/object/async method or what? Be aware, `onload` event isn't fired when adding element to the DOM

Comment: How about the JavaScript that inserts new content?

Comment: @A.Wolff i know, but how do i prepopulate elements before they show up?

Comment: I'm really not sure to see what you mean, maybe you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver   But again, without seeing a concrete sample of what you are looking for, we can only speculate

Comment: @A.Wolff what concrete example else do you need? i gave the concrete use case above. this is almost the same use case like mine

Comment: Need to know how do you add elements? Where in your second HTML markup is `id_1`? What do you need to set, input value or what? Etc... Why not providing a simple jsFiddle? This would make your question more clear

Comment: @A.Wolff ok cool i will give a fiddle when i make it to home. ;) on the train now

Comment: @A.Wolff i added jsfiddle

Comment: @doniyor I'm confused, what is the relation between your jsFiddle and your question `<< jquery delegate onload event-handler for newly created elements >>`. In fiddle, you are only adding DIVs which don't have any relevant onload event. Please read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149076/how-can-i-add-an-event-listener-that-triggers-whan-a-certain-type-of-element-is/46149349#46149349

Answer (score 2):

You could capture event on all browsers which support it:

```
document.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(event){
        var elm = event.target;
        if( elm.id === 'some_elementid'){ // or any other filtering condition
            // do some stuff
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

Comment: this looks good. does this also work for new elements which are created _after_ dom ready?

Comment: @doniyor Ya, even onload event doesn't bubble, you can still capture it to any static praent container. e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/j8y0ow3h/  using onerror event for images

Comment: ``some_elementid`` should be the parent id or the container which is being loaded right now?

Comment: The downside is the support of IE<9 where capturing phase isn't handled

Comment: @doniyor `some_elementid` must be the ID of the element you want to capture the onload event. In posted example, the container is `document`, you could use any static parent, e.g: `$('#container')[0].addEventListener(...);`  ***As side note:*** don't forget IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: this doesnot make sense somehow. I need the chance to change some elements during onload. ``if(elm.id == 'asdasd')`` is just not right for this purpose, what do you think?

Comment: @doniyor Please provide concrete sample of what you are looking for in question, i'm no more sure to understand what you mean